# creating macros for locking range of cell on click of checkbox

Tags: vba, excel

I want to lock certain range of cell  in excel by a click on checkbox.
1. I am adding a checkbox from `developer>>Insert>>ActiveX Checkbox` .

Now I am looking like when clicking on checkbox cell range`A1:A30` should be lock and when I click uncheck for checkbox it should prompt me popup to provide password before unlocking that above range of cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the worksheet of interest and:

1) Click the top left to grey triangle to select all cells

2) Right click Format Cells

3) Ensure Locked box is ticked

4) Go to Review tab and select Protect Sheet and enter your password e.g. "password"

In the code associated with the check box you would have something along the lines of the following. It should give you the general elements.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim myRange as Range
Dim response As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("mySheetName") 'Change as appropriate
Set myRange = ws.Range("A1:A2") 'Change as appropriate

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
    'unlock range  
   response = InputBox("Enter Password")
   If response <> "password" Then 
       Exit Sub 'Or other response such as loop to prompt again
   Else
       ws.Unprotect Password:="password"
       myRange.Locked = False
   End If
Else 
   'range should be locked
    ws.Unprotect Password:="password"
    myRange.Locked = True
End If

ws.Protect Password:="password"

End Sub
```

You would need to lock the VBA project so people can't go into the VBE and retrieve the password.

Some info here on locking:

[VBA Unlock Range](http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/excel-vba-range-lockunlock-specific-cells/)

Comment: I am very new to macros actually.....after running your code I am getting an error "Else Without IF"

Comment: Thanks ........its working fine now