# Lock And Unlock Specified Cells With A Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I need a simple VBA code to lock the cell (or cell range) if i click on a checkbox

e.g - If i click on a checkbox, the cell range e.g A1:A20 should be unlocked and then i can enter some values; if i deselect the checkbox the cell should be locked

Some one can help me with the code.Its throwing me an error "Unable to Set the Locked Property of the Range Class"

Comment: If you show your code, probably we can help.

Comment: Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") '
Set myRange = ws.Range("A1:A20") '

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
       myRange.Locked = False
Else
       myRange.Locked = True
End If

Comment: We cannot understand too much posting your code in a comment. Please, edit your question and place the code there. Did you try unprotecting before locking?

Comment: @FaneDuru Here's the code 

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click() 
Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim myRange As Range 
Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' 
Set myRange = ws.Range("A1:A20") ' 
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
myRange.Locked = False 
Else myRange.Locked = True 
End If –

Comment: Does [this other question on Stack Overflow that has an answer to your question that I found in 4 seconds after searching for your question title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46619742/9663006) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using `ActiveX Checkbox`):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""

    If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
        rng.Locked = False
        rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Else
        rng.Locked = True
        rng.Interior.Color = RGB(220, 220, 220)
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Alex but its acting the reverse way 
what i want is 
Say range A1:A20 is locked and then  If i click on the checkbox the cell or the cell range should be unlocked

and once i untick that checkbox again the data should not be editable

Comment: Remove the `Not` logic.

Comment: user2553598: Your question is asking for the reverse of what you say now...

Comment: @Alexp : It works now thank you so much can i make some more request 
the range should be grey in colour (locked) and if clicked on checkbox that should turn to white (unlocked)..something like this

Comment: Thanks mate you were really helpful today:)

Comment: @AlexP : Mate i encountered a problem ..this code works perfect but there are some cells which should not get locked as those are text fields and should be editable always 
eg A1:A20 range locked/unlocked but cell B1 is a text eg: Name of Project Manager ..and this should not get locked (as the sheet is getting locked)

Comment: and Alex there is one more thing I have inserted 2 checkbox now (cell range C1:C20) and (D1:D20) and i have replicated the same code what is happening is if i have to directly select the checkbox 2 the cell range C1:C20 doesn't get edit . You have to select checkbox 1 compulsory to get the other 2 ranges unlocked 

Can you help on these 2 topics where i am encountering a problem

Comment: 1st issue: for those cells you want to be editable you need to manually set the cell `locked` property. Select cell, `CTRL + 1`, in tab `Protection` uncheck `locked`

Comment: 2nd Issue is now solved it was my mistake i didnt changed the checkbox name :( My Bad ..Thanks mate for all the help :)

Comment: @user2553598: Even if you do not know how to ask a question, when finally somebody asked it in a way to be useful for you, we here tick the left code side check box to make it  accepted answer...

Comment: @alexP - there is a one more requirement. Can you please help. I have given an example below

On clicking a checkbox in on of the sheet in excel the other "Tab(s)" should get enabled/disabled or Appear/disappear

For eg. There is a tab name"Summary" and in Summary sheet1 I have a checkbox. On selecting the checkbox in the sheet1, the sheet 2 should get enabled/disabled or it should appear or disappear

Comment: Use `Worksheets("Sheet2").visible = xlSheetHidden` to hide and `Worksheets("Sheet2").visible = xlSheetVisible` to show

Comment: @AlexP Hello Alex i Need a small favor from you again, i need to enhance my previous code and below is the requirement:
Col A has the 2 options "Yes" or "No" .If i click Yes, Col B and C should be activated and if i select No they should be greyed out

I used this code but not working, rng defined is Col B and C
If Me.Yes.Value Then
        rng.Locked = False
        rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Comment: Hello Can someone please help me fix my code 
the requirement is i have a combo box in Col B2 and when i select the "Yes" from drop down the cells (C2 and D2) should be enabled and when no then should be disabled and greyout

Comment: Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If Range(B2).Value = Yes Then
Range(C2:D2).Locked = False
Else
Range(C2:D2).Locked = True
End IF
End Sub

Comment: @Alex ..can you help me with my code 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("B2") = "Yes" Then
        Range("C2:D2").Locked = True
    Else
        If Range("B2") = "No" Then
            Range("C2:D2").Locked = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Are you using a `ComboBox` in column A with selection values `yes` and `no`? The original code used a `Checkbox` only.

Comment: No its a drop down now ..i got the code but only 1 line is getting reflect 

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "XX"

If Range("B13") = "Yes" Then
    Range("C13:D13").Locked = False
    Range("C13:D13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
        ElseIf Range("B13") = "No" Then
    Range("C13:D13").Locked = True
    Range("C13:D13").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect "XX"
End Sub

Comment: i want to apply this for a range e.g (If Range "B13:B50") = Yes Then Range("C13:D50).Locked = True and so on BUT I am getting a compliation error

Comment: I would start a new question as it is different from the original question. Also the comment thread is becoming too long.

Comment: It doesnt allow me to do so as i have already asked 3 questions and i guess we have a limit so used this forum